# How to force kendoui mobile to use ios theme for Android

Tags: kendo-ui

Is there a way to force kendoui mobile to use same ios theme of my application for both iOs and android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the Kendo UI Mobile [docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/application#forcing-platform-styles) for how to force a platform style.

Answer (score 1):

The theme can be set in the app initialization.

```
    var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, 
    {
        platform: "android"
    });
```

as per http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/mobile/application#configuration-platform